# How do you implement Signals and Events in C++?

Tags: c++, sdl, signals

I am making a Gui Library on top of SDL using C++. (Don't ask me why, I am just doing it to gain some knowledge out of practice in order to understand how Gui libraries are made.) And I want to make a signal connection system like gtk+ or wxWidgets...

```
 g_signal_connect(mybutton,"clicked",gtk_main_quit); //Gtk+

 EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,OnQuit); //WxWidgets
```

I understand I can do this using function pointers. But how do I add the functions to the main loop?

Or Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is borrowing it from a library, for example `boost::signal` or `boost::signal2`. The next best thing is implementing your own but borrowing most of the features from libraries like `boost::bind` (to enable the connections) or using C++0x features that will simplify the generic connection of clients (`std::function` / `boost::function`).

I would recommend that you use `boost` and their `signals2` library, as there are many things that you can do wrong and are already solved there.

Comment: Thanks. (Do u know any place containing good tutorials/articles/docs on using it?)

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals2.html) of boost libraries is usually quite good, and in many cases will contain examples of code. You should probably start there.